# how to start jboss server window service

Tags: java, jboss

can u tell me how can i start sy jboss 5 as window service and then i can start my project directly  from browser

i want that it uses my localhost:8080 port

if any link is there \, i am very thankful to u all.

advance thanks to all

Comment: hi, you need to start the server from default folder, i dont remember the location. but search for run.bat file. and just double click it. Hope u have already created all environment variables which ever required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your JBoss directory. And just run "/bin/service.bat install". JBoss will appear in your Windows Services list.

After that you can use both Windows Services applet and service.bat for starting/stoppping your service.

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer to the following URL:

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-application-server/229-run-jboss-as-service-howto.html

as documentation for using JBoss as windows service...